# Extract number & text from string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
There 10 items in shop A,
There 30 items in shop B.
```

I need extract number & text from the string. The result should:

```
array(
0 => 10 items,
1 => 30 items
);
```

I tried to use this regex:

```
\d+\s\/items
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: So for what did you put `\/` in there?

Comment: Where is the 10 and 30 coming from? Database? Variable name? value is static?

Comment: @Levi Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes... You have to get the logic of what you're trying to do correct else its not going to function the way you want it too.

Comment: @Levi I think you missed that the values are coming from parsing a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string = 'There 10 items in shop A, There 30 items in shop B.';
$matches = null;
preg_match_all('/\d+\sitems/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Would output:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '10 items' (length=8)
      1 => string '30 items' (length=8)
```

Comment: @ryantrantan You are welcome. Feel free to mark it as an answer if it answers your question. Cheers